# Python: query a class's parent-class after multiple derivations ("super()" does not work)

Tags: python, class, parent, super

I have built a class-system that uses multiple derivations of a baseclass
(object->class1->class2->class3):

```
class class1(object):
 def __init__(self):
  print "class1.__init__()"
  object.__init__(self)

class class2(class1):
 def __init__(self):
  print "class2.__init__()"
  class1.__init__(self)


class class3(class2):
 def __init__(self):
  print "class3.__init__()"
  class2.__init__(self)

x = class3()
```

It works as expected and prints:

```
class3.__init__()
class2.__init__()
class1.__init__()
```

Now I would like to replace the 3 lines

```
object.__init__(self)
...
class1.__init__(self)
...
class2.__init__(self)
```

with something like this:

```
currentParentClass().__init__()
...
currentParentClass().__init__()
...
currentParentClass().__init__()
```

So basically, i want to create a class-system where i
don't have to type "classXYZ.doSomething()".

As mentioned above, I want to get the "current class's
parent-class".

Replacing the three lines with:

```
super(type(self), self).__init__()
```

does NOT work (it always returns the parent-class of the
current instance -> class2) and will result in an endless
loop printing:

```
class3.__init__()
class2.__init__()
class2.__init__()
class2.__init__()
class2.__init__()
...
```

So is there a function that can give me the current class's
parent-class?

Thank you for your help!

Henry

## --------------------

Edit:

@Lennart
ok maybe i got you wrong but at the moment i think i didn't describe the problem clearly enough.So this example might explain it better:

lets create another child-class

```
class class4(class3):
 pass
```

now what happens if we derive an instance from class4?

```
y = class4()
```

i think it clearly executes:

```
super(class3, self).__init__()
```

which we can translate to this:

```
class2.__init__(y)
```

this is definitly not the goal(that would be `class3.__init__(y)`)

Now making lots of parent-class-function-calls - i do not want to re-implement all of my functions with different base-class-names in my super()-calls.

I also want to mention that I am kind of new to pythons-class system, so i hope you have patience with me.

Comment: Answer updated. The method called will be class3.__init__(y).

Answer (score 4):

"As mentioned above, I want to get the "current class's parent-class"."

But you know it. In class2 it's class1. So you want to call class1. Always. So then you could just call class1.

But the correct way to the the current class's parent-class is super(). But you used it like this:

```
super(type(self), self)
```

And that will get you the parent class of the class of self. And the class of self in your case is class3, so as you note, it always return class2. The correct way of using it is as follows:

```
class class1(object):
 def __init__(self):
  print "class1.__init__()"
  super(class1, self).__init__()

class class2(class1):
 def __init__(self):
  print "class2.__init__()"
  super(class2, self).__init__()


class class3(class2):
 def __init__(self):
  print "class3.__init__()"
  super(class3, self).__init__()


x = class3()
```

The difference between using super() and calling the class directly is if you are using multiple inheritance somewhere in the hierarchy. Super will then figure out which is the correct class.

---

Update:

What happens when you define a class4 and call it?

```
>>> class class4(class3):
...  pass
... 
>>> y = class4()
class3.__init__()
class2.__init__()
class1.__init__()
```

As you say, the goal is to call `class3.__init__()`. This is exactly what happens, as class4 will inherit `__init__` from class3, according to normal inheritance rules.

You expected `class2.__init__()` to get called, but I don't understand why you expect that. You inherit from class3, so it's `__init__` will be the one that is called. It in turn calls `class2.__init__` per design.

Comment: thank you for your answer and suggestions but your solution is definitely not what i am looking for.

i want to create multiple child-classes and inherit functions that must call their parent's functions and not "class3"'s (or any other hard-coded class-name).

Comment: @henry: That's not a problem. super() is *still* the correct answer. Note that the hardcoded classname is **not** the classname of the parent, but the classname of the class it's called **from**. What super() does is figure out WHAT THE PARENT IS so you DO NOT have to hard code that parents name. So super() *is* the correct answer for you.

Comment: i think this is a misunderstanding. please see my edit above. i hope this makes things clear.

Comment: Definitely a misunderstanding. :) You still want super(). Really.

Answer (score 0):

You are after the `__bases__` member of `__class__`.  The parent of your class is available like this:

```
>>> class A: pass

>>> class B(A): pass

>>> class C(B): pass

>>> C.__bases__[0]
<class __main__.B at ...>

>>> C.__bases__[0].__bases__[0]
<class __main__.A at ...>
```

But, remember your class can have multiple parents.

```
>>> class D: pass

>>> class E(A,D): pass

>>> E.__bases__
(<class __main__.A at ...>, <class __main__.D at ...>)
```

What you are up to is, in my opinion, seldom worthwhile.  But it is fun to know how Python itself keeps track of the furniture needed for multiple inheritance.

Answer (score -4):

You can't do it without frame inspection, and that's frowned upon.

Here's a implementation I found on the net that does frame inspection:

```
import sys

class _super(object):
    __name__ = 'super'

    __slots__ = ('_super__super', '_super__method')

    def __init__(self, super, name):
        object.__setattr__(self, '_super__super', super)

        try:
            object.__setattr__(self, '_super__method', getattr(super, name))
        except AttributeError:
            object.__setattr__(self, '_super__method', name)

    def __call__(self, *p, **kw):
        method = object.__getattribute__(self, '_super__method')

        try:
            return method(*p, **kw)
        except TypeError:
            if type(method) is not str:
                raise

        super = object.__getattribute__(self, '_super__super')
        method = getattr(super, method)
        object.__setattr__(self, '_super__method', method)
        return method(*p, **kw)

    def __getattribute__ (self, name):
        super = object.__getattribute__(self, '_super__super')

        try:
            return getattr(super, name)
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
            if name == 'super':
                raise TypeError("Cannot get 'super' object of 'super' object")

            raise

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super = object.__getattribute__(self, '_super__super')
        object.__setattr__(super, name, value)

def _getSuper(self):
    frame = sys._getframe().f_back
    code = frame.f_code
    name = code.co_name

    cur_class = None

    for c in type(self).__mro__:
        try:
            m = getattr(c, name)
            func_code = m.func_code
        except AttributeError:
            func_code = None

        if func_code is code:
            cur_class = c
        elif cur_class is not None:
            break

    if cur_class is None:
        raise TypeError, "Can only call 'super' in a bound method"

    return _super(super(cur_class, self), name)

class autosuper(object):
    __slots__ = ()
    super = property(_getSuper)
```

Your code when using it:

```
class class1(autosuper):
    def __init__(self):
        print "class1.__init__()"
        self.super()

class class2(class1):
    def __init__(self):
        print "class2.__init__()"
        self.super()


class class3(class2):
    def __init__(self):
        print "class3.__init__()"
        self.super()

x = class3()
```

On [python3, `super()` is already magical](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#super) and can work without passing the class:

```
super().method(args)
```

Comment: Urgl. OK, nosklo, sorry for downvoting you, but don't encourage the guy to do this stuff when he shouldn't. :)

Comment: he suggested 2 solutions to the problem. i understand why the frame-inspection way is frowned upon, but it's a solution that solves the problem in my case. switching to python 3 was another good suggestion, i think.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: I'm glad you downvoted me. Seems that stackoverflow is improving at least - in the past it was all about answering the question, no matter how bad it is. I think you should downvote the question instead, though

Comment: @henry: The only difference between Python3 and Python2 here is that in Python 3 it will figure out the class name by itself.